# Can I extract yaw, pitch and roll from XYZ and/or latitude, longitude and altitude information

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, rotations

I have a problem regarding my programming project and I'm stuck on the mathematical side of the problem.

I am parsing geometrical data from a provider and from their side every information is provided, but because of access problems, I don't have access to every field and my task is to recalculate the values when they get parsed. I still have the original data so that I can check if my calculations are right (or close enough).

I have access to the latitude, longitude and altitude information as well as the ECEF coordinates. Because of my limited geometry/trigonometry knowledge my problem is that I don't know if its even possible to extract that data from the info I have, and if so in what way.

I managed to recaluclate ECEF coordinates from latitude ,longitude but I wasn't successful with pitch, roll, yaw.

Data that I we acquire from provider (JSON):

```
 "pos": {
     "pitch": -0.839661672,
     "roll": -1.663901733,
     "x": -2707284.431485295,
     "y": -4262211.770268887,
     "yaw": 1.160845159,
     "z": 3883714.949993163
 },
 "lat_lng": {
     "height": -8.501139877, <- altitude
      "lat": 37.751917496,
      "lng": -122.423062823
 }
```

Data I have access to (JSON):

```
 "pos": {
     "pitch": ?, <- need this
     "roll": ?, <- need this
     "x": -2707284.431485295, <- calculated from lat_lng
     "y": -4262211.770268887, <- calculated from lat_lng
     "yaw": ?, <- need this
     "z": 3883714.949993163 <- calculated from lat_lng
 },
 "lat_lng": {
     "height": -8.501139877, <- altitude
      "lat": 37.751917496,
      "lng": -122.423062823
 }
```

As I understood I need a rotation matrix which can be easily converted to pitch, yaw ,roll. Formulas that I'm planning to use (found on other threads):

```
roll = math.atan2( -R[2][0], math.sqrt((R[2][1] * R[2][1]) + (R[2] 
[2] * R[2][2])) )
pitch = math.atan2( R[1][0], R[1][1] )
yaw = math.atan2( R[2][1], R[2][2] )
```

EDIT: Not homework, work related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I extract yaw, pitch and roll from XYZ and/or latitude, longitude and altitude information

No. The spherical coordinates (latitude, longitude, altitude) and the Cartesian coordinates (ECEF) both specify a **location** -- you can calculate one set of coordinates from the other. But (pitch, roll, yaw) specifies an **orientation**, and none of the data you show seem related to that. (Rotation matrices serve to convert between various representations of an orientation, but they don't help if you don't have some representation to begin with.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I just noticed that we do have access to one more field called "heading", would that information be enough to calculate it?

Comment: @anonymousbh "Heading" (="bearing"= direction of travel) is *one of three* angles that would be needed to specify an orientation; e.g., (bearing, elevation, bank) can be converted to (yaw, pitch, roll). I'm not really familiar with the varied terminology, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait%E2%80%93Bryan_angles) has some explanation: "For an aircraft, [bearing, elevation, bank] can be obtained with three rotations around its principal axes if done in the proper order. A yaw will obtain the bearing, a pitch will yield the elevation and a roll gives the bank angle."